# I can not give id value in the modal part

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

```
<div class="table">
  ....
    <tr *ngFor="let product of products; index as i">
      <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
      <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.category }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ product.quantity ? "not over" : "it's over" }}</td>
      <th>
        <button
          class="btn btn-warning ml-2"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#updateProduct"
          (click)="fetchProduct(product._id, updateModal)"
        >
          UPDATE
        </button>
        <button
          class="btn btn-danger ml-2"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#deleteProduct"

        >
          DELETE
        </button>
      </th>
    </tr>
   ....
 </div>
```

```
<div
  class="modal fade"
  id="deleteProduct"
  data-backdrop="static"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <h4>Are you sure you want to delete?</h4>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 mr-2"
          data-dismiss="modal"
        >
          CANCEL
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary ml-2 mr-2"
          (click)="deleteProduct(product._id)"
        >
          DELETE
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

These two blocks of code are in the same HTML page.

My goal is to remove a warning modal when the delete key is pressed in the table. And then press the delete button on the modal to delete the existing line.
But I can't get the `id` value I returned here in the modal part.

Normally when I do this without a modal in the table it works fine because I can take the `id` value and delete it directly. But I don't know how to give this `id` value when I am out.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your ts create new variable:

```
deleteID : any;
```

in your html add below code:(inside ngFor)

```
<button
          class="btn btn-danger ml-2"
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#deleteProduct"
(click)="deleteID= product._id"
        >
          DELETE
        </button>
```

inside modal:

```
<button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary ml-2 mr-2"
          (click)="deleteProduct(deleteID)"
        >
          DELETE
        </button>
```

hope it will be help.